# PowerShell Command to Disable PPTP Remote Access Connections

Tags: windows, vpn, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, pptp

I'm trying to automate the creation of a L2TP VPN server using PowerShell but I can't find any articles or cmdlets on how to disable PPTP inbound connections in RRAS using PowerShell. Below is a screenshot of the setting I'm trying to disable via PowerShell:

[image]

Additionally if there's a command to set the "Maximum Ports:" that would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`netsh`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753876(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_setwanports):

```
netsh ras set wanports device="WAN Miniport (PPTP)" rasinonly=disabled maxports=128
```

Comment: Ah okay this work perfectly! I was assuming the option to disable this would be a RRAS PowerShell cmdlet. Thanks for your help Mathias!